# Finding Global minima

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, softmax

I have a neural network and am struggling to find the global minima. I would like to know the right approach to finding it. I know I need to change the hyperparameters but because you use random weights, do I try using the same hyperparameters multiple times? How many different combinations do I try before I give up?

Any practical advice would be appreciated.

Comment: To find the global minimum of a loss function, many applications split their data into batches and process the batches in a random order. This is the stochastic gradient descent (SGD) method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the major drawback of gradient descent based optimization. They get stuck in local minima all the time and there is **no** way of guaranteeing a global minima solution.

You can use terms like momentum to help you get over some local minima. I would suggest trying some more advanced optimization technique. These will help you a bit because they select and update some of these hyperparameters automatically.

You can also look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340221/which-method-for-training-neural-networks-works-best) post right here which compares several optimization algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a way to find a global minima for a NN with gradient descent (assuming thats what your using).  I think you can find it with an SVM though.

Im not a machine learning expert so i could be wrong.